# In Cut the Rope 2, what do I do after finding a hidden star in a video?

Tags: cut-the-rope-2

In the Cut the Rope 2, each video says it has a hidden star to find. What should I do if I have found one? Is there any reward for finding one? If there is, how can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing to do once you've found one - they're just little extras that Zepto hide in all their Cut the Rope videos.

They tend to [challenge people on social media](https://twitter.com/cut_the_rope/status/261513415514787840) to find the stars, so my best guess is that they're there to encourage people to share the videos.